# Add profile picture to listview in navigation drawer

Tags: android, listview

This is the listview in my navigation drawer (It's generated by android studio). I'm new to android development and I don't understand how I can add a user's profile picture to the top of the list.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
                    getString(R.string.title_section4),
            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

Ideally, I want it to be like in the Google Plus app: http://www.v3.co.uk/IMG/851/267851/google-plus-android-multi-accounts-370x229.png?1376557059

Comment: how do you want the picture to be displayed... any model or screenshot?

Comment: Like the Google+ app: http://www.v3.co.uk/IMG/851/267851/google-plus-android-multi-accounts-370x229.png?1376557059

Comment: you'll need no create a custom Layout for the ListView item of the Navigation Drawer and inflate it.